# jQuery datatable ajax error not hitting the server

Tags: datatable, datatables

I have the below code to run a post to get the data to the datatable.
However, the post doesn't being hit at all and I get an error from the datatable saying "ajax error for more info go [http://datatables.net/tn/7"](http://datatables.net/tn/7%22). The info there is saying I get an error 500 from the server - but I can't manage even to get a breakpoint hit on the server.
Am I missing something here? What am I doing wrong?
I just want to debug the server side code and see what is going on....

```
    $('.mytable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: appUrl + 'my post method in the controller',
            data: { startPage: startPage, startIndex: recordsToSkip, recCount: recCount },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                console.log(data);
            }....
```

and on the server I have this at the end of my method:

return Json(result);

Comment: A "500" error on the server should be causing a stack trace to be logged on the server (in log files or on the console). If your code is swallowing the exception, then you may not see anything, of course - so check for that, also.

Comment: In addition: (1) Do not use the ajax `success` function inside your DataTable definition - see [`ajax.datasrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) for an explanation. (2) You do not have to manually build a `data` section for things such `startPage` if that data is already covered by the data provided by DataTables - see [server-side sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for details.